# Bathtub Leak when Drain Clogs

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, basement, shower

I get a leak from my bathtub but only when the drain’s clogged. Before I pay a bunch to get it inspected, can I get any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Does this leak also occur when you intentionally fill the bathtub? How high does the water rise in the tub when this occurs? How high is the tub's overflow? "when the drain's backing up" -- what are the conditions when that occurs, and what causes it to clear?

Comment: @GregHill thank you for your time. By backing up I mean when the drain is clogged, and so it drains slowly.

Comment: What do you mean by "leak"? Does water from the tub leak onto the floor below? Also, what sort of stopper is used for the drain?

Answer (score 2):

Put the stopper in and fill the tub. Check the stopper is actually watertight.

If it leaks, then the leak is above the stopper. If it leaks only when water reaches the overflow, then it's the overflow. Otherwise, it's the joint around the drain hole on the inside of the tub (red arrow).

If it doesn't leak with the stopper in, but leaks when the drain is clogged, then the leak is between the drain hole and the place where it clogs, so that's probably one of the joints (blue arrows). The most likely culprit is the joint between the drain assembly and the tub.

If the thing is accessible, it isn't difficult to fix.

For example if the screw that holds the drain assembly against the tub is not tightened, then the joints will not be watertight, and it will leak at the place where the tub contacts the drain assembly. You can grab the thing from below and wiggle it, see if it stays in place or if it is loose.

[image]